# is it relevant to raise $e$ with the following $\ln(x^2) = \ln(x+2)$ to make in equivalent?

Tags: analysis

I am currently taking a course in one dimensional analysis and I came across this example:
$$2\ln(x)=\ln(x+2)\\
\ln(x^2)=\ln(x+2)\\
e^{\ln(x^2)}=e^{\ln(x+2)}\\
x^2=x+2\\
...\\
x_1 = -1 (\text{false})\\
x_2 = 2$$

It the book they stated that the equation is not an equivalent equation if $e$ is not raised with $\ln(x^2)$ and $\ln(x+2)$  on each side respectively.

If I would have NOT used $e$ and just went on and said that $\ln(x^2) = \ln(x+1)$ is an equivalent equation would I run into mathematical errors. I am asking both for this case and other cases of $\ln(a) = \ln(b)$, whatever $a$ and $b$ might be.

Comment: It may help if you quote the book's exact words. I've done my best to answer, but I'm unsure if the book is making the point that I think it is.

Comment: @J.G. it's written in another language so maybe "equivalent equations" means something else in the English language. The book basically states that it is mathematically incorrect to, at least in this case, say that inside of $\ln(x^2)$ is the same as in $\ln(x+1)$ meaning that solving it as is might have unwanted results (e.g. might be the wrong answer). I am asking if this is correct. Will I, for real numbers of x, get the wrong answer if I solve for what is inside the natural logarithm parenthesis on each side or is it mathematically equivalent/the same as solving for the exponent of $e$?

Answer (score 2):

While each root of the original equation must be $-1$ or $2$ so as to solve $x^2-x-2=0$, note $x=-1$ doesn't work because it's not a positive choice for the argument of $\ln x$. In general, $\ln x^2=2\ln x$ if $\ln x$ is defined (as happens if $x>0$), while $\ln a=\ln b$ if $a=b$ provided $\ln a, \, \ln b$ are defined (as happens if $a, \, b>0$.

Note: the above considers real logarithms; the complex case is left as an exercise for interested readers.